# jQuery click function (halting a click function until previous click function has completed)

Tags: jquery

I have been working on zoom function. Suppose a user clicks on zoom function continuously, the actual math coordinate calculations varies that with the actual coordinates shown. So, I want to know if I can halt another click until the previous click has completed?

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to achieve. However, JS is single threaded, only one event is executed at any moment in time. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/EventLoop

Comment: have you tried to use flag to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to off or unbind the click event while previous one is in progress and then   on or bind it once previous event has completed.

Or Easier way to do this would be to disable the element as soon as it is clicked until previous event has finished executing.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of halting another click, why not just bind and unbind the click event? For example...

```
function aClick() {
  $( "div" ).show().fadeOut( "slow" );
}

$( "#bind" ).click(function() {
  $( "#theone" ).bind( "click", aClick ).text( "Can Click!" );
});

$( "#unbind" ).click(function() {
  $( "#theone" ).unbind( "click", aClick ).text( "Does nothing..." );
});
```